# Entities Framework 4 Code First: Inheritance

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, code-first

I am currently trialing EF4 code-first. My POCO classes inherit from an Audit class that contains CreatedBy, CreatedOn, UpdatedBy, UpdatedOn. I was hoping the framework would include the Audit properties in my Action table when creating my database, however this doesn't appear to be the case. Does anyone know how to enable this without overriding the OnModelCreating() method?

```
Public Class Audit
    Public Property CreatedOn as DateTime
End Class

Public Class Action
    inherits Audit
    Public Property ActionId As Int32
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the ComplexType of Code First, Such as below, I think it is good for OOD

```
[ComplexType]
public class CreateType
{
    public DateTime CreateOn { get; set; }


    public string CreateBy { get; set; }

    ...
}

public class Action
{
    public int ActionId { get; set; }

    public CreateType CreateType { get; set; }
}
```